# What text changes were made for the 2013 Deluxe OD&D reprint?

Tags: odnd

I’ve heard references to text having been removed for the reprinted boxed set of the original *Dungeons & Dragons* booklets, published by Wizards of the Coast in 2013, but I haven’t ever found a detailed explanation of the alleged changes. [The most recent mention](https://www.dmsguild.com/m/product/28306) of this I’ve stumbled over goes so far as to call it “censored”, and *heavily* at that:

> This is the heavily censored 2013 version, …

That review on the PDF edition also doesn’t elaborate what changes the objection is based on. (Googling has failed me, and when I thought I’d have to resign myself to digging through forums I remembered that’s exactly what SE exists to avoid.)

I haven’t seen a 2013 print copy, and don’t have ready access to a copy of the original printing to compare it with anyway. (I’ve always had to reference a friend’s copy.) I will probably get a copy of the PDFs as a reference that’s finally my own, but I want to know what I might be missing.

What (if any) textual changes were made or text was removed for the 2013 WotC reprints of OD&D, compared to the original 1974 TSR edition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### A single reference to "hobbits" on page 6.

Someone who owns the very earliest printing of Dungeons & Dragons may indeed notice more differences—but these would be changes made between the original printing (1974) and sixth printing (1977), which notably removed several references to the works of Tolkien.

The 2013 reprint makes virtually no changes (even the art of the scantily clad Amazon remains!), except as follows:

- On page 6, the line "Fighting-Men includes the characters of elves and dwarves and even hobbits" was changed to say "halflings" instead.

  - According to [The Acaeum](https://www.acaeum.com/ddindexes/setpages/original.html)'s page on the topic, the sixth printing in 1977 is believed to be the edition which removed references to hobbits, balrogs, ents, etc, owing to a lawsuit by Saul Zaentz, who in 1976 purchased exclusive merchandising rights to *The Hobbit* and *The Lord of the Rings*. However, this edition missed a single reference to hobbits on page 6, which WotC was no doubt legally required to change for the reprint.
- Men & Magic is now referred to as Book I, rather than Volume I. This convention is used throughout the books.
- The cover art is new, and of professional quality.
- Wizards of the Coast's logo appears on the 2013 product. TSR's address and a product listing of TSR products are omitted.

The complaint of censorship may refer to the replacement of the cover art of *Eldritch Wizardry*, which originally shows a naked woman tied to an altar. All of the reprints were given new cover art, including that book.

Comment: As JRR Tolkien passed away in 1973, presumably the changes to the 1977 edition were due to a lawsuit by the Tolkien *estate*, which is an altogether different situation...

Comment: Thanks. I've corrected it. Interestingly, it seems the lawsuit was actually from a third party who had bought the rights from the Tolkien estate, rather than from the Tolkien estate themselves.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. I was confusing the seventh printing (1978-1979) which according to The Acaceum only changed the catalog page.